# Could not launch android emulator in android studio

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I am running android studio in Ubuntu 14.04.

Whenever I launch my application , It ask me to choose the emulator .

And I used to click OK to launch new emulator and when i do so I am getting this error .

```
/home/sudhir/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none -wipe-data

Could not launch '/home/sudhir/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator64-x86': Permission denied
```

Please help me

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have some permissions issues, you need to have the permission x (execute) for the emulator. Try:

```
ls -l /home/sudhir/Android/Sdk/tools/
```

And check if you have the execute permissions on the emulator. If not, try:

```
chmod +x emulator64-x86
```

Well, hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it .and the emulator appeared like pop up window and again disappeared ..and  I got this different error.....-avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
PANIC: .//android/sockets.c:1087:socket_accept: System call looped around EINTR 100 times: accept(fd, addr.sa, &addrlen)

Comment: this worked for me +1 but now I get qemu could load PC BIOS 'bios.bin'

Answer (score 0):

do like for emulator permission settings

chmod +x /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86

chmod +x /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator

chmod +x /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator-x86